# Sephardi Minhag of Boy Taking Maftir at Age 9

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, torah-reading, minor-katan-child, maftir, torah-service

Could someone point me to the source of the custom where typically within the Sephardic communities, it is customary for a boy to be called for maftir/hafatarah at the age of 9 years.

Is this brought down in the Mishna? Or, what is the earliest mention of Rabbanic rulings regarding this custom?

I guess to some extent, this is also similar to what the Ashkenazim permit on Simchat Torah?!

Thanks, KT!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[O Ch 284 (4)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14171&st=&pgnum=126) starts with the words that someone under barmitzvah (age not specified) can say the maftir.

The source is a gemoro in [Megilo 23a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=23&format=text).

Comment: Thanks Avrohom. Just wondering, any chance we’ve got access to the English versions of these sources; or at least the SA/MB?

Comment: The following two links are **partial** translations of Shulchan Oruch [link 1](http://www.shulchanarach.com/) and [link 2](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Shulchan_Aruch/Orach_Chaim#Sabbath)

This [link](http://www.torah.org/advanced/shulchan-aruch/classes/orachchayim/chapter20.html) is a summary which lacks the detail in this question.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok - Your answer only states permissability of someone under Bar Mitzvah to read maftir. Is there a source for the Minhag Sephardim that they do this at age 9?

Comment: 9 is the age of chinuch for Yom Kippur see [Yoma 82a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=6&daf=82&format=text) but I have not found the specific source for saying maftir.

Comment: @Larry A translation of the *Mishna B'rura* (284:7) can be found [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=1kF9RT8oVg0C&pg=PA71#v=onepage&q&f=false). The MB doesn't elaborate on the exact age necessary, though. Regarding the [age of *chinuch*](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1208) in general, see *Gitin* ([59a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=19&daf=59&format=text)), *Yoma* ([82a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=6&daf=82&format=text)), Rashi ([*Arachin* 2b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=33&daf=2b&format=text), s.v. שהגיע לחינוך), and Tosafos (ibid.).

Comment: ...For more on the age of *chinuch* in general, see [here](http://www.dinonline.org/2014/04/26/parashas-emor-the-meaning-of-chinuch/) and [here](http://www.ahavasolam.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/The-Proper-Age-of-Chinuch-2-19-12.pdf).